# Optimization of naive matrix multiplication (ICC vs GCC)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, icc

The code below uses a very straightforward approach to calculate the matrix product `a * b` and store the result in `c`.  The code was compiled with `-O3` on both GCC 4.4.6 (with `-mtune=native`) and Intel Compiler 13.0.1 and the speed on GCC is significantly worse (over a factor of two for the sample data used).

I'm curious about the cause of these differences, but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the assembly output to understand what's going on here.  From a glance it looks as though ICC is doing a better job at vectorizing the computation, but I can't decipher much more than that.  (This is mainly for learning purposes since there's no way I would use this in production!)

```
void __attribute__ ((noinline)) mm(                            // Line 3
    int n,
    double*__restrict__ c,
    double*__restrict__ a,
    double*__restrict__ b
) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            c[i + n * j] = 0;                                  // Line 12
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                c[i + n * j] += a[i + n * k] * b[k + n * j];   // Line 14
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from GCC:

```
_Z2mmiPdS_S_:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushq   %r14    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 14, -16
    testl   %edi, %edi  # n
    movq    %rcx, %r14  # b, b
    pushq   %r13    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    .cfi_offset 13, -24
    pushq   %r12    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 12, -32
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    .cfi_offset 6, -40
    pushq   %rbx    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    .cfi_offset 3, -48
    jle .L6 #,
    leal    -1(%rdi), %eax  #, tmp96
    movslq  %edi, %r11  # n, n
    movq    %rdx, %rbx  # a, ivtmp.54
    xorl    %r12d, %r12d    # ivtmp.67
    salq    $3, %r11    #, D.2193
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp  # prephitmp.37
    leaq    8(,%rax,8), %r13    #, D.2208
.L3:
    leaq    (%rsi,%r12), %r10   #, ivtmp.61
    movq    %r14, %rcx  # b, ivtmp.63
    xorl    %edx, %edx  # j
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L5:
    movq    $0, (%r10)  #,* ivtmp.61
    movq    %rbp, -8(%rsp)  # prephitmp.37,
    movq    %rcx, %r9   # ivtmp.63, ivtmp.70
    movsd   -8(%rsp), %xmm1 #, prephitmp.37
    movq    %rbx, %r8   # ivtmp.54, ivtmp.69
    xorl    %eax, %eax  # k
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L4:
    movsd   (%r8), %xmm0    #* ivtmp.69, tmp99
    addl    $1, %eax    #, k
    addq    %r11, %r8   # D.2193, ivtmp.69
    mulsd   (%r9), %xmm0    #* ivtmp.70, tmp99
    addq    $8, %r9 #, ivtmp.70
    cmpl    %edi, %eax  # n, k
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm1    # tmp99, prephitmp.37
    movsd   %xmm1, (%r10)   # prephitmp.37,* ivtmp.61
    jne .L4 #,
    addl    $1, %edx    #, j
    addq    %r11, %r10  # D.2193, ivtmp.61
    addq    %r11, %rcx  # D.2193, ivtmp.63
    cmpl    %edi, %edx  # n, j
    jne .L5 #,
    addq    $8, %r12    #, ivtmp.67
    addq    $8, %rbx    #, ivtmp.54
    cmpq    %r13, %r12  # D.2208, ivtmp.67
    jne .L3 #,
.L6:
    popq    %rbx    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    popq    %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    popq    %r12    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    popq    %r13    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r14    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

And here is the output from ICC:

```
# -- Begin  _Z2mmiPdS_S_
# mark_begin;
       .align    16,0x90
    .globl _Z2mmiPdS_S_
_Z2mmiPdS_S_:
# parameter 1: %edi
# parameter 2: %rsi
# parameter 3: %rdx
# parameter 4: %rcx
..B1.1:                         # Preds ..B1.0
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.1:                                  #8.3
        pushq     %r12                                          #8.3
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.3:                                  #
        pushq     %r13                                          #8.3
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.5:                                  #
        pushq     %r14                                          #8.3
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.7:                                  #
        pushq     %r15                                          #8.3
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.9:                                  #
        pushq     %rbx                                          #8.3
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.11:                                 #
        pushq     %rbp                                          #8.3
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.13:                                 #
        subq      $72, %rsp                                     #8.3
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.15:                                 #
        movq      %rsi, %r9                                     #
        movslq    %edi, %rax                                    #
        xorl      %r10d, %r10d                                  #11.9
        testl     %edi, %edi                                    #11.25
        jle       ..B1.7        # Prob 10%                      #11.25
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbx rbp rsi r9 r12 r13 r14 r15 edi r10d
..B1.2:                         # Preds ..B1.1
        movl      %edi, %r11d                                   #10.5
        lea       (,%rax,8), %r8                                #
        andl      $-4, %r11d                                    #10.5
        movq      %rax, %r14                                    #12.28
        movslq    %r11d, %r11                                   #10.5
        movl      %edi, %r12d                                   #12.28
        movq      %rsi, 8(%rsp)                                 #12.28
        movq      %r8, %rbp                                     #12.28
        movq      %rdx, 32(%rsp)                                #12.28
        movq      %r9, %r13                                     #12.28
        movq      %rcx, (%rsp)                                  #12.28
        movl      %r10d, %r15d                                  #12.28
        pxor      %xmm0, %xmm0                                  #12.28
        movq      %r11, %rbx                                    #12.28
                                # LOE rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.3:                         # Preds ..B1.5 ..B1.48 ..B1.45 ..B1.2
        cmpl      $12, %r12d                                    #10.5
        jle       ..B1.38       # Prob 0%                       #10.5
                                # LOE rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.3
        movq      %r13, %rdi                                    #12.13
        xorl      %esi, %esi                                    #12.13
        movq      %rbp, %rdx                                    #12.13
        call      _intel_fast_memset                            #12.13
                                # LOE rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.5:                         # Preds ..B1.4
        incl      %r15d                                         #11.9
        lea       (%r13,%r14,8), %r13                           #11.9
        cmpl      %r12d, %r15d                                  #11.9
        jb        ..B1.3        # Prob 82%                      #11.9
                                # LOE rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.6:                         # Preds ..B1.48 ..B1.45 ..B1.5  # Infreq
        movl      %r12d, %edi                                   #
        movq      %r14, %rax                                    #
        movq      8(%rsp), %rsi                                 #
        testl     %edi, %edi                                    #11.25
        movq      32(%rsp), %rdx                                #
        movq      (%rsp), %rcx                                  #
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbx rbp rsi r12 r13 r14 r15 edi
..B1.7:                         # Preds ..B1.1 ..B1.6           # Infreq
        movl      $0, %r9d                                      #11.9
        movl      $0, %r8d                                      #
        jle       ..B1.33       # Prob 10%                      #11.25
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbx rbp rsi r8 r12 r13 r14 r15 edi r9d
..B1.8:                         # Preds ..B1.7                  # Infreq
        movq      %rdx, 32(%rsp)                                #
                                # LOE rax rcx rsi r8 edi r9d
..B1.9:                         # Preds ..B1.31 ..B1.8          # Infreq
        xorl      %r12d, %r12d                                  #
        lea       (%rsi,%r8,8), %r13                            #14.17
        movq      %r13, %r15                                    #10.5
        xorl      %ebx, %ebx                                    #13.13
        andq      $15, %r15                                     #10.5
        xorl      %r10d, %r10d                                  #
        movl      %r15d, %r14d                                  #10.5
        lea       (%rcx,%r8,8), %rbp                            #14.48
        andl      $7, %r14d                                     #10.5
        xorl      %r11d, %r11d                                  #
        movl      %r14d, 48(%rsp)                               #
        xorl      %edx, %edx                                    #
        movl      %r15d, 56(%rsp)                               #
        movq      %r13, 40(%rsp)                                #
        movq      %r8, 16(%rsp)                                 #
        movl      %r9d, 24(%rsp)                                #
        movq      %rsi, 8(%rsp)                                 #
        movq      %rcx, (%rsp)                                  #
        movq      32(%rsp), %r14                                #
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r10 r12 r14 ebx edi r11d
..B1.10:                        # Preds ..B1.30 ..B1.9          # Infreq
        cmpq      $8, %rax                                      #10.5
        jl        ..B1.34       # Prob 10%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r10 r12 r14 ebx edi r11d
..B1.11:                        # Preds ..B1.10                 # Infreq
        movl      56(%rsp), %r9d                                #10.5
        testl     %r9d, %r9d                                    #10.5
        je        ..B1.14       # Prob 50%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r9 r10 r12 r14 ebx edi r11d
..B1.12:                        # Preds ..B1.11                 # Infreq
        cmpl      $0, 48(%rsp)                                  #10.5
        jne       ..B1.34       # Prob 10%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r10 r12 r14 ebx edi r11d
..B1.13:                        # Preds ..B1.12                 # Infreq
        movl      $1, %r9d                                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r9 r10 r12 r14 ebx edi r11d
..B1.14:                        # Preds ..B1.13 ..B1.11         # Infreq
        movl      %r9d, %r13d                                   #10.5
        lea       8(%r13), %rcx                                 #10.5
        cmpq      %rcx, %rax                                    #10.5
        jl        ..B1.34       # Prob 10%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r9 r10 r12 r13 r14 ebx edi r11d
..B1.15:                        # Preds ..B1.14                 # Infreq
        movl      %edi, %r15d                                   #10.5
        xorl      %ecx, %ecx                                    #10.5
        subl      %r9d, %r15d                                   #10.5
        movslq    %r11d, %r8                                    #14.33
        andl      $7, %r15d                                     #10.5
        negl      %r15d                                         #10.5
        addl      %edi, %r15d                                   #10.5
        movslq    %r15d, %r15                                   #10.5
        testq     %r13, %r13                                    #10.5
        lea       (%r14,%r8,8), %rsi                            #14.33
        jbe       ..B1.35       # Prob 0%                       #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r8 r9 r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d
..B1.16:                        # Preds ..B1.15                 # Infreq
        movsd     (%r10,%rbp), %xmm0                            #14.48
        movq      40(%rsp), %r14                                #14.48
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r8 r9 r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.17:                        # Preds ..B1.17 ..B1.16         # Infreq
        movsd     (%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm1                          #14.33
        mulsd     %xmm0, %xmm1                                  #14.48
        addsd     (%r14,%rcx,8), %xmm1                          #14.17
        movsd     %xmm1, (%r14,%rcx,8)                          #14.17
        incq      %rcx                                          #10.5
        cmpq      %r13, %rcx                                    #10.5
        jb        ..B1.17       # Prob 82%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r8 r9 r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.18:                        # Preds ..B1.17                 # Infreq
        movq      32(%rsp), %r14                                #
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp rsi r8 r9 r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.19:                        # Preds ..B1.18 ..B1.35         # Infreq
        addq      %r9, %r8                                      #14.33
        lea       (%r14,%r8,8), %rcx                            #14.33
        testq     $15, %rcx                                     #10.5
        je        ..B1.23       # Prob 60%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp rsi r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.20:                        # Preds ..B1.19                 # Infreq
        movq      40(%rsp), %rcx                                #14.48
        unpcklpd  %xmm0, %xmm0                                  #14.48
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.21:                        # Preds ..B1.21 ..B1.20         # Infreq
        movsd     (%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm1                          #14.33
        movsd     16(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm2                        #14.33
        movsd     32(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm3                        #14.33
        movsd     48(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm4                        #14.33
        movhpd    8(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm1                         #14.33
        movhpd    24(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm2                        #14.33
        movhpd    40(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm3                        #14.33
        movhpd    56(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm4                        #14.33
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm1                                  #14.48
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm2                                  #14.48
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm3                                  #14.48
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm4                                  #14.48
        addpd     (%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm1                          #14.17
        addpd     16(%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm2                        #14.17
        addpd     32(%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm3                        #14.17
        addpd     48(%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm4                        #14.17
        movaps    %xmm1, (%rcx,%r13,8)                          #14.17
        movaps    %xmm2, 16(%rcx,%r13,8)                        #14.17
        movaps    %xmm3, 32(%rcx,%r13,8)                        #14.17
        movaps    %xmm4, 48(%rcx,%r13,8)                        #14.17
        addq      $8, %r13                                      #10.5
        cmpq      %r15, %r13                                    #10.5
        jb        ..B1.21       # Prob 82%                      #10.5
        jmp       ..B1.26       # Prob 100%                     #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.23:                        # Preds ..B1.19                 # Infreq
        movq      40(%rsp), %rcx                                #14.48
        unpcklpd  %xmm0, %xmm0                                  #14.48
        .align    16,0x90
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.24:                        # Preds ..B1.24 ..B1.23         # Infreq
        movaps    (%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm1                          #14.33
        movaps    16(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm2                        #14.33
        movaps    32(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm3                        #14.33
        movaps    48(%rsi,%r13,8), %xmm4                        #14.33
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm1                                  #14.48
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm2                                  #14.48
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm3                                  #14.48
        mulpd     %xmm0, %xmm4                                  #14.48
        addpd     (%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm1                          #14.17
        addpd     16(%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm2                        #14.17
        addpd     32(%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm3                        #14.17
        addpd     48(%rcx,%r13,8), %xmm4                        #14.17
        movaps    %xmm1, (%rcx,%r13,8)                          #14.17
        movaps    %xmm2, 16(%rcx,%r13,8)                        #14.17
        movaps    %xmm3, 32(%rcx,%r13,8)                        #14.17
        movaps    %xmm4, 48(%rcx,%r13,8)                        #14.17
        addq      $8, %r13                                      #10.5
        cmpq      %r15, %r13                                    #10.5
        jb        ..B1.24       # Prob 82%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.26:                        # Preds ..B1.24 ..B1.21 ..B1.34 # Infreq
        cmpq      %rax, %r15                                    #10.5
        jae       ..B1.30       # Prob 0%                       #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r10 r12 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d
..B1.27:                        # Preds ..B1.26                 # Infreq
        movsd     (%rbp,%r12,8), %xmm0                          #14.48
        lea       (%r14,%rdx,8), %rcx                           #14.33
        movq      40(%rsp), %rsi                                #14.48
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r10 r12 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.28:                        # Preds ..B1.28 ..B1.27         # Infreq
        movsd     (%rcx,%r15,8), %xmm1                          #14.33
        mulsd     %xmm0, %xmm1                                  #14.48
        addsd     (%rsi,%r15,8), %xmm1                          #14.17
        movsd     %xmm1, (%rsi,%r15,8)                          #14.17
        incq      %r15                                          #10.5
        cmpq      %rax, %r15                                    #10.5
        jb        ..B1.28       # Prob 82%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbp rsi r10 r12 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.30:                        # Preds ..B1.28 ..B1.26         # Infreq
        incl      %ebx                                          #13.13
        addq      %rax, %rdx                                    #13.13
        addl      %edi, %r11d                                   #13.13
        addq      $8, %r10                                      #13.13
        incq      %r12                                          #13.13
        cmpl      %edi, %ebx                                    #13.13
        jb        ..B1.10       # Prob 82%                      #13.13
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r10 r12 r14 ebx edi r11d
..B1.31:                        # Preds ..B1.30                 # Infreq
        movl      24(%rsp), %r9d                                #
        incl      %r9d                                          #11.9
        movq      16(%rsp), %r8                                 #
        addq      %rax, %r8                                     #11.9
        movq      8(%rsp), %rsi                                 #
        cmpl      %edi, %r9d                                    #11.9
        movq      (%rsp), %rcx                                  #
        jb        ..B1.9        # Prob 82%                      #11.9
                                # LOE rax rcx rsi r8 edi r9d
..B1.33:                        # Preds ..B1.31 ..B1.7          # Infreq
        addq      $72, %rsp                                     #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.16:                                 #
        popq      %rbp                                          #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.18:                                 #
        popq      %rbx                                          #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.20:                                 #
        popq      %r15                                          #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.22:                                 #
        popq      %r14                                          #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.24:                                 #
        popq      %r13                                          #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.26:                                 #
        popq      %r12                                          #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.28:                                 #
        ret                                                     #18.1
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.29:                                 #
                                # LOE
..B1.34:                        # Preds ..B1.10 ..B1.14 ..B1.12 # Infreq
        xorl      %r15d, %r15d                                  #10.5
        jmp       ..B1.26       # Prob 100%                     #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp r10 r12 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d
..B1.35:                        # Preds ..B1.15                 # Infreq
        movsd     (%rbp,%r12,8), %xmm0                          #14.48
        jmp       ..B1.19       # Prob 100%                     #14.48
                                # LOE rax rdx rbp rsi r8 r9 r10 r12 r13 r14 r15 ebx edi r11d xmm0
..B1.38:                        # Preds ..B1.3                  # Infreq
        cmpq      $4, %r14                                      #10.5
        jl        ..B1.47       # Prob 10%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.39:                        # Preds ..B1.38                 # Infreq
        xorl      %esi, %esi                                    #10.5
        movq      %rbx, %rdx                                    #10.5
        movq      %r13, %rcx                                    #
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #
        pxor      %xmm0, %xmm0                                  #
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbx rbp rsi r13 r14 r12d r15d xmm0
..B1.40:                        # Preds ..B1.40 ..B1.39         # Infreq
        addq      $4, %rsi                                      #10.5
        movq      %rax, (%rcx)                                  #12.13
        movhpd    %xmm0, 8(%rcx)                                #12.13
        movq      %rax, 16(%rcx)                                #12.13
        movhpd    %xmm0, 24(%rcx)                               #12.13
        addq      $32, %rcx                                     #10.5
        cmpq      %rbx, %rsi                                    #10.5
        jb        ..B1.40       # Prob 82%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rax rdx rcx rbx rbp rsi r13 r14 r12d r15d xmm0
..B1.42:                        # Preds ..B1.40 ..B1.47         # Infreq
        cmpq      %r14, %rdx                                    #10.5
        jae       ..B1.48       # Prob 0%                       #10.5
                                # LOE rdx rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.43:                        # Preds ..B1.42                 # Infreq
        xorl      %ecx, %ecx                                    #
                                # LOE rdx rcx rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.44:                        # Preds ..B1.44 ..B1.43         # Infreq
        movq      %rcx, (%r13,%rdx,8)                           #12.13
        incq      %rdx                                          #10.5
        cmpq      %r14, %rdx                                    #10.5
        jb        ..B1.44       # Prob 82%                      #10.5
                                # LOE rdx rcx rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.45:                        # Preds ..B1.44                 # Infreq
        incl      %r15d                                         #11.9
        lea       (%r13,%r14,8), %r13                           #11.9
        cmpl      %r12d, %r15d                                  #11.9
        jb        ..B1.3        # Prob 82%                      #11.9
        jmp       ..B1.6        # Prob 100%                     #11.9
                                # LOE rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.47:                        # Preds ..B1.38                 # Infreq
        xorl      %edx, %edx                                    #10.5
        jmp       ..B1.42       # Prob 100%                     #10.5
                                # LOE rdx rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
..B1.48:                        # Preds ..B1.42                 # Infreq
        incl      %r15d                                         #11.9
        lea       (%r13,%r14,8), %r13                           #11.9
        cmpl      %r12d, %r15d                                  #11.9
        jb        ..B1.3        # Prob 82%                      #11.9
        jmp       ..B1.6        # Prob 100%                     #11.9
        .align    16,0x90
..___tag_value__Z2mmiPdS_S_.36:                                 #
                                # LOE rbx rbp r13 r14 r12d r15d
# mark_end;
    .type   _Z2mmiPdS_S_,@function
    .size   _Z2mmiPdS_S_,.-_Z2mmiPdS_S_
    .data
# -- End  _Z2mmiPdS_S_
```

**Edit:** With the help of Olaf Dietsche, it looks like the code below can run much faster with GCC 4.8.2, though still a bit (~30%) slower than Intel.  The main difference is that the initialization is done ahead of time (this by itself makes no difference) and the loop ordering has been interchanged (this makes a major difference for GCC).

```
    memset(c, 0, n * n);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                c[i + n * j] += a[i + n * k] * b[k + n * j];   // Line 14       
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: icc assumes '-ffast-math' but gcc does not.

Comment: if you want good matrix manipulation, try Intel MKL.

Comment: I'm just using this code as an example for understanding the differences in compiler optimization, not so much for actual matrix multiplication.

Comment: Using `-ffast-math` doesn't appear to affect the speed here and the assembly output is nearly the same as well.

Comment: Your gcc output is clearly not vectorized.  mulsd is a single multiply of the lower 64 bit [used in the gcc output].  In contrast, mulpd is a packed multiply (2 multiplies at once - lower by lower and upper by upper) [used in icc].  I think that is the primary difference.  You're running half as many multiply instructions due to SIMD usage in ICC.  Loop unrolling helps, but the major effect is from SIMD.  See here to see if you can turn it on with gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html.  NOTE that O3 alone is not enough because it doesn't know what instruction set to use.

Comment: I've used `-msse`, `-msse2`, `-msse3` and none of them make any noticeable difference in actual performance.

Comment: I appreciate your analysis though.  So it does appear that gcc is failing to fully vectorize the code.

Comment: Can you provide the gcc/icc versions?

Comment: Oops.  Just realized I've been using the default compiler on the node, which is a GCC 4.4.6.  The Intel compiler is 13.0.1.  Using GCC 4.8.2 provides a moderate increase in speed (20%).

Comment: If you are serious in modifying the algorithm itself, you should try block matrix multiplication http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/autoblock/node2.html then worry about compiler optimization

Comment: `-mtune=<foo>` tells the GCC to generate code that will run on whatever the default target CPU happens to be, but try to tune instruction selection for CPU `<foo>`. Try throwing a full `-march=<foo>` at it instead, [I get what looks like a more heavily vectorized code generation.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8faf0dbb94b5bd5a)

Comment: `-march=native` doesn't seem to affect the speed, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems to be wrong or not suitable for vectorization.

When I modify your code according to this blog post [Performance – GCC & auto-vectorization](http://warppipe.net/blog/?p=498)

```c++
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            c[n * i + k] += a[n * i + j] * b[n * j + k];   // Line 14
        }
    }
}
```

and compile it with

```
gcc-4.8 -O3 -S a.c
```

it uses at least some SIMD instructions

```
.L8:
    movsd    (%rcx), %xmm1
    addl     $1, %r8d
    movsd    (%rdx,%rsi), %xmm2
    unpcklpd %xmm1, %xmm1
    movhpd   8(%rdx,%rsi), %xmm2
    movsd    (%rax,%rsi), %xmm0
    mulpd    %xmm2, %xmm1
    movhpd   8(%rax,%rsi), %xmm0
    addpd    %xmm1, %xmm0
    movlpd   %xmm0, (%rax,%rsi)
    movhpd   %xmm0, 8(%rax,%rsi)
    addq     $16, %rsi
    cmpl     %r8d, %ebx
    ja       .L8
    cmpl     %edi, %r15d
    je       .L9
```

although not as much as ICC does.

*Update:*

Adding `-funroll-loops` enlarges the generated assembly code substantially to about the length of your posted ICC assembly.

Comment: This does improve the speed quite a bit!  Though still a bit behind ICC the speed is much closer now (~30%).  As usual, `-funroll-loops` has negligible effect here.  However, does this really produce the same result?

Comment: Maybe now, you see a performance difference with `-msse3` or later.

Comment: I fixed the initialization (line 12).

Comment: The initialization is still wrong though, as you're using a variable `k` that lives in an inner scope.  I think I figured it out though, see my edited question.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I removed the initialization altogether.

Comment: Does ICC generate other or faster code as well with the new version?

Comment: Didn't check the assembly in ICC but the code takes the same amount of time to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Intel compiler is using SIMD instructions (`mulpd`, `addpd`, `movaps` etc) -- it's able to perform more than one operation (i.e. both a = b*c and d = e*f) in a single clock cycle, whereas the GCC code would take two to do the same.. I'm not sure if it's possible to enable these operations automatically in GCC, but you can hand-write them in with some work.

It seems like the flags -msse, -msse2, -msse3 to GCC cause it to attempt to do some SIMD optimization of its own.

Comment: Which is to say that ICC *auto vectorized* the code.  GCC can too, with `-ftree-vectorize` along with telling it what level of SSE to use, e.g. `-msse2`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for the tip with the GCC flags, all SIMD code I've written before was done manually with e.g. `_mm_add_ps` and its ilk

Comment: gcc's auto vectorization is not quite mature yet.  it's not able to work in a lot of cases that it should.  looks like this is one of those cases, although it looks simple enough.  on ARM, I've seen it done better ARM NEON than I can, but for some reason, this gives it hiccup.  Something about the form of the code.

Comment: I've tried using `-msseN` and sadly it doesn't affect the performance noticeably in this scenario.  (Also, `-ftree-vectorize` is implied by `-O3`.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if ICC really produced faster code in this case because I didn't run any actual benchmarks.  But you can tell GCC to unroll the loops with `-funroll-loops`.  The output will be longer, will contain lots of `xmm`'s and will *look* faster.

Comment: Alas, the difference it makes in the actual speed appears to be negligible in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Neither icc nor gcc necessarily optimizes the degree of unrolling.  To match them, you would use e.g.
gcc -funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=4
icc -unroll4
as gcc tends to unroll more than optimum for CPUs of the last 8 years (if allowed to do so) while icc is more conservative.
Also glossed over above is that icc -O3 encourages the compiler to optimize loop nesting, and may even engage the special -opt-matmul facility.
The original form implies a dot product reduction inner loop, for which gcc might require both -ffast-math and a more modern choice for -march= in order to optimize.  icc is much more aggressive about riffling a dot product (batching into multiple sums), if it can't avoid it by switching loop nest.